# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain cause crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, release, retain

This is a weird one, but I think I'm just missing something simple.

I have an Objective C class called Theme.
Themes load all the art for my game from files and stores them in a NSMutableArray.

When the app launches it reates a new Theme object.
Part of the loading process does something like this:

```
UIImage *image = [self mergeImage: bg toImage: overlay];
[imageArray addObject: image];
```

I take a background image and place the overlay on top of it, creating a new UIImage, by using this code:

```
- (UIImage *)mergeImage:(UIImage *)image1 toImage:(UIImage *)image2 { 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image1.size);  

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.size.width, image1.size.height)];  

[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image2.size.width, image2.size.height)];  

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
//[resultingImage retain];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  

return resultingImage;
}
```

All of this happens in the init function of Theme.
Here's the problem, when I call [[Theme alloc] init] from

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

The app crashes a second later, leaving me with no stack or anything(I figure it screws up some memory and crashes later when it uses it again or something).

Here's the weird part. If I don't add the newly merged image to the imageArray, it never crashes. I don't have the image anymore, but there's no crash. Also, if I don't add the image to the array, but I retain it in the mergeImage function, it does crash, which makes me think that retaining this newly-made image is causing the problem.
Weirder still, if I don't call mergeImage until later on in the app, outside of teh [Theme init] and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, it's OK.

Any idea why? What's wrong with retaining this image when the app first launches?

Comment: Is your imageArray initialized by the time you add the new image inside it?

Comment: did you check if resultingImage is not nil ?

Comment: I am not using ARC.
My ImageArray is alloced and inited before this.
A UIImage is created, so the value is not nil.
When I'm done, the imageArray has an object that is not nil, and it does call retain on that object, I can even check the retainCount in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Below Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.bounds.size); 
[drawImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return viewImage
```

Thanks..!

Comment: What type of object is drawImage? I get errors if drawObject is a UIImage*

Comment: Well it didn't exactly work, but it got me down the right path so I'm marking this as answered.
I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was, but I found that if I merged the image in a different function from the one that created it, it worked. So I just made 2 function, one to create and one to merge, and call them both from init.